# Push value to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with multiple values and need to push a value into this array.

The orignial array looks like:

```
[0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Name" ["id"]=> string(8) "134567" }
[1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "Name" ["id"]=> string(9) "123456" }
```

And I need to put these values into the above array:

```
$personal['id']
$personal['name']
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use square bracket notation to append to the original array:

```
$original[] = $person;
```

Or if `$person` is more complex and you only want those two keys:

```
$original[] = array(
        'name' => $personal['name'],
        'id' => $personal['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `$personal` array only contains `id` and `name` you could use `array_push`.

```
array_push($array, $personal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the guy who gave me the answer deleted his answer,

But this I used to add values to

```
 $originalArray[]['id'] = $personal['id'];
 $originalArray[]['name'] = $personal['name'];
```

Anyway ++1 for you, thanks! :)

Comment: Wouldn't this push 2 entries, one containing only `id` and the other containing only `name`?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
$yourarray[]=$personal;
```